# MassTransit message encryption and routing slip events

Tags: masstransit, routing-slip

I have enabled encryption for my RabbitMQ bus as per MassTransit documentation:

```
bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rabbit =>
{
    rabbit.Durable = true;
    
    rabbit.Host(new Uri(settings.ServerUri), h =>
    {
        h.Username(settings.Username);
        h.Password(settings.Password);
    });

    rabbit.ClearMessageDeserializers();
    rabbit.UseEncryption(Convert.FromBase64String("..."));

    ...
});
```

I have also added subscription for a routing slip completed event:

```
var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(NewId.NextGuid());
builder.AddActivity(...);
await builder.AddSubscription(queueUri, RoutingSlipEvents.Completed,
                x => x.Send<xxxRoutingSlipCompleted>(new { ctx.Data.CorrelationId }));
```

While all other messages get encrypted as expected, routing slip events get sent in plain text (as can be seen in RabbitMQ queue) and result in the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 
No deserializer was registered for the message content type: application/vnd.masstransit+json.
Supported content types include application/vnd.masstransit.v2+aes 
at MassTransit.Serialization.SupportedMessageDeserializers.Deserialize(ReceiveContext receiveContext) 
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next) 
at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
```

Is there some additional configuration that needs to be applied to routing slips (I can't see anything relevant on the ISendEndpoint interface) or is this a bug in MassTransit?

Comment: Is the same serializer configuration applied to the endpoints hosting the routing slip activities? That's where the events are produced, which seem to currently be serializing using the default JSON serializer.

Comment: I thought that enabling encryption on the bus level would be global, but I also invoked the same code (ClearMessageDeserializers/UseEncryption) against the same instances of IReceiveEndpointConfigurator that were used to configure the activity (eg ConfigureActivityExecute, ConfigureExecuteActivity, ConfigureActivityCompensate) and and it didn't fix the issue. Is there a separate endpoint for the events that needs to be explicitly configured as well?

Comment: You might need to leave the JSON deserializer in place, I think the events are published using JSON since it transforms the event for the subscription.

Comment: "I think the events are published using JSON" - so it is not possible to have the events encrypted and they are always published in plain json? Or am I misreading this?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, yes. For subscriptions, at least.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Hi Chris, I've been going through the MassTransit source code in the past couple of days and I think I found where this issue potentially resides. In RoutingSlipEventPublisher.cs there is the following line: var adapter = new MessageEnvelopeContextAdapter(null, subscription.Message, JsonMessageSerializer.ContentTypeHeaderValue, message);. MessageEnvelopeContextAdapter is hardcoded to use json serialization but I can't really see any reason it can't use a crypto serializer there if necessary. Could you please confirm you still believe it is a feature and not a bug? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the events are transformed using the JSON serializer, so I'm not sure how you'd get from transformed JSON to the encrypted format based upon the configured serializer. It's more of a limitation, and not a priority for me. You're welcome to come up with a solution and submit a PR.

Comment: I am of course not familiar enough with the MT internals, but I thought that that code was the final hop that delivers the event to the consumer endpoint, so it is only a matter of serializing the message envelope to the transport and everything was in json prior to that. I also thought that message encryption only affects what gets sent to the broker, and is transparent for everything else, so if EnvelopeMessageSerializer was to use a crypto serializer and the receiving endpoint was configured to use a crypto deserializer it would just work. Am I misunderstanding all of this?